# I Have an issue while map the shoppingcart items. Getting this error TS2339: Property 'items' does not exist on type 'unknown'

Tags: angular, typescript

*shopping-cart.service.ts*

```
import { Product } from 'shared/models/product';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { ShoppingCart } from 'shared/models/shopping-cart';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

    @Injectable()
    export class ShoppingCartService {
      constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

      async getCart(): Promise<Observable<ShoppingCart>> {
        const cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
        return this.db
          .object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId)
          .map(x => new ShoppingCart(x.items));  **// Getting error at x.items **
      }

      async addToCart(product: Product) {
        this.updateItem(product, 1);
      }
```

*I am getting this error*

> error TS2339: Property 'items' does not exist on type 'unknown'

Comment: What is the value of `x`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a type on x. By default implicit 'any' type is not allow.
So you have 3 choices you can use [] notation, you can set the type to any

```
 .map((x:any) => new ShoppingCart(x.items));
```

or type it

```
interface CartResponse {
    items:Array;
}

.map((x:CartResponse) => new ShoppingCart(x.items));
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see on the code you are missing this import

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `x['items']` if you know for sure that `x` is valid object. Otherwise set `console.log(JSON.stringify(x))` to see what is inside `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the type/interface of X if you know, otherwise use x:any in argument of map(if you use lint it will throw warning)